# Woocommerce - Remove minus (-) from sale price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please let me know how I can remove - *(minus)* from a Woocomerce shop page. Right now, on shop page it's display line-through regular price and red price with minus before for sale price.

I just need to remove that minus. On single page product i have just red price without minus before.

Comment: How are u displaying the price?

Comment: Use trim($price, '-');

Comment: How? Default woocommerce shop page!

Comment: Wich is tha page where i must insert trim($price, '-'); ?

Comment: Have you customized any woocommerce modules?

Comment: no, i have no modification in code.

Comment: [link]http://postimg.org/image/nb1xqm8hz

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS please can u tell me where i must insert that code. Please see my link with print screen. Best regards

Comment: What themes/plugins are you using and what woocommerce version?

Comment: @axxis theme Rebound with plugins: contact-form, layerslider, woocommerce

Comment: Evrika! I found it! On tw_woocommerce.css at line 1929 i just add display:none; before close } like

<code>
 .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price ins:before,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .price ins:before {
    content: '-';
    padding: 0 4px;
 display:none;
}
</code>